# Laravel - Query scope with relationship objects

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got and eloquent model with a many-to-many relationship, on which's table I store some additional fields. I then use a query scope to get those fields and return them with my model as follows:

```
public function scopeWithAllocatedPractitioners($query)
    {
        $query->with(['allocated_practitioners' => function ($query)
        {
            $query->select([
                'practitioner_id',
                'completion_status_id',
                DB::raw('ifnull(overtime_hours, 0) as overtime_hours'),
                'avatar',
                'first_name',
                'last_name'
            ]);
        }]);
    }
```

The *completion_status_id* field refers to the identified of another model called *ShiftCompletionStatus*. What I want to do, is to get other fields from that model and include them in this query scope so that the returned object would look something like this:

```
allocated_practitioners: [
    {
        "practitioner_id: ...,
        "completion_status": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Not started"
        }
        ...
    }
]...
```

I'm thinking that I could maybe use some DB::raw swag or else use the *with* callback to create the object in my select array. It would almost mean doing something like this:

```
public function scopeWithAllocatedPractitioners($query)
{
    $completion_status_object = // somehow get the model instance by getting info from the query
    $query->with(['allocated_practitioners' => function ($query)
    {
        $query->select([
            'practitioner_id',
            'completion_status' => $completion_status_object,
            DB::raw('ifnull(overtime_hours, 0) as overtime_hours'),
            'avatar',
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        ]);
    }]);
}
```

But this doesn't work... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you must use **whereHas()**

```
public function scopeWithAllocatedPractitioners($query)
    {
        $query->whereHas('allocated_practitioners', function ($query)
        {
            $query->select([
                'practitioner_id',
                'completion_status_id',
                DB::raw('ifnull(overtime_hours, 0) as overtime_hours'),
                'avatar',
                'first_name',
                'last_name'
            ]);
        }]);
    }
```